# Resize thousands of images all to different sizes in batch. Name and size are given in excel file. How to do it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, script

Pardon me if this is a duplicated question even though I could not find a solution yet. I have about 1000s images. I need to resize them, each to a specific size. There are no patterns to those sizes. They are different. I have the file names and the sizes in an excel file. Manually it will take a lot of time. I was wondering if this can be done in a batch process. Maybe Photoshop Scripting or something else.

I do not know how to script but have the general idea of how it works.

What I want to do is indicate the folder and the excel/csv/text file and the batch will run and resize each file to the given height keeping the proportion.

### Example:

1000s of Image files.

Named: file1, file2, file3, file4. etc...

file1 will have 975 px height

file2 will have 486 px height

file3 will have 846 px height

All keeping the proportions.

Hope that clarifies what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Leave this one open, it is not a duplicate, the data is on a csv file, which makes the question interesting.

Comment: @Danielillo : No, it is not. My problem is say I have file 1, file 2, file 3. file 1 will have 905 px height, file 2 will have 826 px height, and so on.

Comment: Scripting time. Or you can just learn to use imagemagic as its easier to find how to do this in imagemagick forums ;)

Comment: @joojaa: Thanks for your reply. Can you kindly be more elaborate. I would like to avoid scripting as I am not used to it. Will Imagemagick allow me to accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: @CrimsonCape well its not really possible to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's going to be quite a simple script actually. You need only to know the basics of JavaScript (if you don't know those, taking a free CodeAcademy or similar web course on basics will only take you several hours)

Then Google will be your best friend. You need to read your file and get all the lines ([first link from google](http://www.joshwright.com/tips/reading-and-writing-text-files-from-photoshop-scripts) on "photoshop script how to read file"), to get an array of lines (in the example above it's not an array, but we already learned the basics of JS and can easily modify it, right?).

You'll [loop through this array](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20how%20to%20loop%20array&oq=javascript%20how%20to%20loop%20array&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4383j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and for every element (aka line from .csv file) you'll want [to split](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20how%20to%20split%20text&oq=javascript%20how%20to%20split%20text&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.4991j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) it by `,` or `;` or whatever you use in your csv — this way you'll get another array that will contain file name and sizes — let's call it `myCSVData`.

Next you'll be just opening your files and resizing them. To get Photoshop specific JavaScript functions and methods you'll use [this document](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2019.pdf) — for example from it we can learn that to open a file we'll need `app.open(File)` function. And to resize we'll use `Document.resizeImage()`.

Here's an algorithm how I'd do that (I'm not a real coder so it might be not the most efficient one):

```
// I also first save current ruler units
// and next make sure they're in pixels or we'll have a disaster 
var originalUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

// I presume csv file consists of lines similar to this (second number is height):
//file1.png,200
//file2.png,350
var b = new File("/c/test.csv");

// open file for reading
b.open('r');
var lines = [];
while (!b.eof)
    lines.push(b.readln()); // got an array of lines
b.close();

// looping through lines array
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
    // creating an array from the line: [filename,height]
    var myCSVData = lines[i].split(',');

    // opening a file
    var docToResize = app.open(new File('/c/imagesFolder/' + myCSVData[0]));

    // resizeImage accept several different arguments but first two are width and height. 
    // if width is undefined and only height is there, width will be proportional to new height.
    // also currently myCSVData[1] is a string, not number, so I convert it to number first
    docToResize.resizeImage(undefined, parseInt(myCSVData[1]));

    docToResize.save(); // saving to the same file
    docToResize.close(); // closing it      
};

// restoring original ruler units
app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalUnits;
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. I copied it into a text file, renamed the extension to .jsx and trying now. So far it is not doing anything. I am tweaking the script to make it work for me. As I am not a programmer it is of course taking quite some trial and error however thanks a lot for giving me this boost up. I will post update once I can make it work.

Comment: By not doing anything, do you mean it doesn't even show any errors? Maybe you're not running it? It's supposed to work or show an error if something isn't right

Comment: It does not show me any error, which is good but I am not being able to make it work yet. I am tweaking and trying some trial and error. Will post back when I have something. Thanks for the Script of course.

Comment: Hi, I have tried myriad ways. I changed the folder paths in different ways, tried the way you have arranged it, everything I could think of. From Photoshop I run the script from File > Script > Browse and show where the script is, and that's it. It does not do anything at all. When I tried to modify it, it showed some errors which probably was my fault but other than that nothing.

Comment: I have been able to open the file and resize it now however, the resizing is not working properly. It is now shrinking the image to 1 x 1. In the code, how am I storing the Height data to the array? Also, I am getting another error of 1233 saying "Expected a reference to an existing File/Folder". It is due to the app.open command. I put together some codes from here and there. Not sure how to post it though. Just copy pasting.

Comment: I am not being able to make it work. 
var docToResize = app.open(new File('/c/imagesFolder/' + myCSVData[i]));
An error is being shown in this line saying a reference to an existing file/folder is required. Error 1233 .
I have been trying to fix it for some time but with no result so far. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The path is wrong probably. It's difficult to say without input data and you folder structure.

Comment: The path is correct. I have changed the path and tried a lot of combinations just to make sure, with forward slashes, backward slashes, with colons, without colons but all the same.

Comment: Maybe the part in `myCSVData` is incorrect? For example in your comment above you're using `myCSVData[i]` instead of `myCSVData[1]`

Comment: I also tried that. I tried 0, 1 etc. I used i because that is the variable to go there correct? How do I send the code that I am using so if you have time, maybe you can check?

Comment: var b = new File("E:/test.csv"); var docToResize = app.open(new File("E:/PNG/" + myCSVData[i])); Rest is as you have send me.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's difficult to say without seeing your csv file. Upload it somewhere please (http://pastebin.com for example)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/03z5yhqriumxx1b/test.csv?dl=0

Comment: so in your case it should be `myCSVData[0]`. What you can do is before opining a file alert what file PS is trying to open with `alert([new File("E:/PNG/" + myCSVData[0]), new File("E:/PNG/" + myCSVData[0]).exists])` — this will show a path and if the file exists in that location

Comment: From alert, I found that the path is adding an extra "%22" before the file name when working with CSV, which was causing all the problems. To make sure I transferred the data to text file and tested, it worked absolutely correct. Rather than CSV, I can work with TXT too so thanks a lot.